# Shuttle SZ87R6 with 3x SSHD 2TB hard drives doesn't boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, sata, uefi

### Hardware:

- 1x Shuttle SZ87R6 with 500W power supply
- 1x Intel i7-4790
- 4x G.Skill 8GB, DDR3-1600, CL10-10-10-30 (F3-12800CL10S-8GBXL)
- 1x Samsung SSD 850 Evo 250 GB (With linux openSuSE 13.2)
- 3x Seagate ST2000DX001 2TB SSHD 3,5" 7.200 rpm hard drives    Used as
  Linux software raid 5    Seagate spec: 2 A per drive for startup.

UEFI firmware version SZ87R000 2.03 (latest) in Legacy mode
Set as boot device only the Samsung SSD 850 Evo 250 GB

Build up system without 3x 2TB hard drives. First time system booted with 3x SSHD  hard drives. After creating software RAUD 5 boot process stops after the sentence `Press <DEL> or <ESC> to enter setup`.

When from 2 drives the SATA data cable is removed (power cable remains) system boots properly.

Have set sata to hot swap, can attach SATA cables after linux has booted. All drives work fine then.

Connected, with adapter cable, SATA drives to another cable, problem still exists.

Is this a power startup problem?

Haven't found any delayed startup setting in BIOS as well as in the S.M.A.R.T. spec.

Comment: Recap: It stops **after** creating a 4TB RAID 5 array, and with the UEFI firmware set in legacy mode. This make me curious, how did you create the array? Normal mdadm or UEFI firmware with intel fake RAID? Did you clear meta data off the disks before creating a the array (esp. if you played with RAID setups before).

Comment: I forgot: 500 Watt should be more than enough to power that system. You probably could run it with a PSU with half that capacity.

Answer (score 0):

> Intel Smart Response Technology

Ensure this is OFF, only thing that I can see that might cause this other than a poor SATA controller which is unlikely here.

NB: Not sure using SSHDs in a RAID is the best idea.

Comment: SSHD's in RAID might be 'interesting'. The on disk firmware should still remember what is read most and cache that in the flash part. So I guess I should stillboost performance.

Comment: 16GB of usable flash isnt really of note when your array is ~3.7TB of usable space. Especially with no boot files. So no benefit, but the really big loss of no TLER support. Spending more to get less IMO.

Comment: Agreed that 16GB of flash is not much, but it could be useful. E.g. when an often played game is installed on those disks. The loss of TLER is not nice though, though I would rank it with 'regular consumer disks' rather than  with the flash part.